# Turn return into variable

Tags: php, function

I have the below function to get the number of days between 2 days, excluding weekends

```
function getWorkingDays($startDate, $endDate)
{
    $begin = strtotime($startDate);
    $end   = strtotime($endDate);
    if ($begin > $end) {
        echo "startdate is in the future! <br />";

        return 0;
    } else {
        $no_days  = 0;
        $weekends = 0;
        while ($begin <= $end) {
            $no_days++; // no of days in the given interval
            $what_day = date("N", $begin);
            if ($what_day > 5) { // 6 and 7 are weekend days
                $weekends++;
            };
            $begin += 86400; // +1 day
        };
        $working_days = $no_days - $weekends;

        return $working_days;


    }
}
```

This works fine, however how do i turn the return into a variable to echo/use?

Comment: $working_days = getWorkingDays($start, $end);

Comment: How *did* you know it works fine?

Comment: He probably just called the function and echoed out the result in there

Comment: You need to learn basic PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt - Thanks

Comment: Side note: please don't get too used to `86400` and other manual date maths. Not all days have 24 hours! `$begin += 86400;` is more reliably rewritten as `$begin = strtotime('+1 day', $begin);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You save it into some variable and then you can print it out:

```
$workingDays = getWorkingDays("some date", "another date");
echo $workingDays;
```

Or, if you only want to use it to print it out you can leave out the variable:

```
echo getWorkingDays("some date", "another date");
```